# Looking for a plugin for "0 results" pages

Tags: search, search-terms, search-result

I'm looking for a plugin or extension that will be able to customize and show "realted products"/"best sellers" or catagories if there are no results found. Also be able to customize it with suggestions and related terms.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get module suggestions, please use this:

https://community.magento.com/t5/Find-an-Extension-that/bd-p/find-extension

People there will go out of their way to help you find what you need, and build it for you if it doesn't exist.